# Post more files and save them into db - django

Tags: python, html, django

i am trying to save more files into db. i am sending with `POST` and catching in server in this way:

html: 
`<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="images[]"/>`

server code - django:

`images = request.POST.getlist('images[]')`. but what i get thru this is only an empty array. `[]`.

now my problem is that i dont know how to save those files along with other data at once into db. well, i thought, i would run a loop over `images[]` but i have other data also in the hand

EDIT: for example, i have streetname,city,country and 3 fotos of one location. if i loop over 3 images, i will save streetname,city,country three times in db which is dumb. i want to save 3 pictures of one location and other data only once. now one solution came to my head: i will make separate table named `Image` then i have two places to save: images separately and data separately to different tables. am i fine with this solution?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    images = request.POST.getlist('images[]')
    other_field = request.POST.get('other_field')

    for i in range(len(images)):
        data = MyModel()
        data.images = images[i]
        data.other_field = other_field
        data.save()
```

Comment: thanks, but i have to save other_field then so many times as the number of my images? :(

Comment: can you complete your codes in your question so that I can picture out. Maybe I can find a solution.

Comment: LOL, maybe you need a ManyToManyField if you want to save three images in one location. Other solution is what you have mention, create other model for Image

Comment: Catherine, i cannot catch the posted files in serverside. i am getting empty array. why is this?

Comment: post new question about that